# codepen scroll function not working or console

Tags: html

My code project on codepen has no working Javascript. The console.logs are not running within my javascript. I have a Div with the id and class set to "text1"

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".text1").css("color: red");
  });

const masterEl = document.getElementById('text1')
console.log(masterEl)
console.log("masterEl")
```

Comment: did you included jQuery to your code?

Comment: Yes I have included it

Comment: show us your html, you are talking about `class` and later getting by `id`...